# Golang: can WaitGroup leak with go-routines

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency

I am planning to implement a go-routine and have a `sync.WaitGroup` to synchronize end of a created go-routine. I create a thread essentially using `go <function>`. So it is something like:

```
main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for <some condition> {
        go myThread(wg)
        wg.Add(1)
    }
    wg.wait()
}

myThread(wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
}
```

I have earlier worked with `pthread_create` which does fail to create a thread under some circumstances. With that context, is it possibly for the above `go myThread(wg)` to fail to start, and/or run `wg.Done()` *if the rest of the routine behaves correctly*? If so, what would be reported and how would the error be caught? My concern is a possible leak in `wg` due to `wg.Add(1)` following the thread creation. (Of course it may be possible to use `wg.Add(1)` within the function, but that leads to other races between the increment and the main program waiting).

I have read through numerous documentation of go-routines and there is no mention of a failure in scheduling or thread creation anywhere. What would be the case if I create billions of threads and exhaust bookkeeping space? Would the go-routine still work and threads still be created?

Comment: Why the -1 please?

Comment: It's like asking "Can a `if` statement fail? E.g. `if true { }`?" Nothing guarantees that the go routine will run but the go statement itself cannot "fail".

Comment: Thanks @Volker but you see it is subtly different from other languages. Can you tell me if we can figure out that the go routine won't run? I am worried about the WaitGroup leak in case it doesn't run.

Comment: No you cannot "find out". If your goroutine does something which blocks endlessly you won't hit wg.Done. But you won't "leak". All you have is a buggy program. But I'm not sure if I understand your problem. If you want your main goroutine to pass wg.Wait you must make sure that your myThread returns in one way or the other.

Comment: @Volker the issue is that I do a wg.Add(1) in the main thread after creating the go-routine, and then in the main thread I do a wg.Wait() for all threads to exit. If the routine is not scheduled at all, there will be no decrement (wg.Done()) and hence the main thread will wait indefinitely.

Comment: I read your code and I do understand it. But the problem you are constructing is an artificial one, it has nothing to do with goroutines or the go keyword. With `go myThread(wg)` you start a new goroutine which is something which *cannot* fail. Of course you can power down your computer during execution of this statement or the process kan be killed or dozens of other things can prevent *the* *whole* *process* to stop but the goroutine start in it self *will* execute and *will* *not* fail. Just like an `i++` does not "fail".

Comment: Whether the goroutine executes code which actually makes progress and reaches the final wg.Done depends only on your code. E.g. `for {}` or `select{}` might block. Again, this is totally unrelated to the goroutine. There are no hard guarantees how much CPU a goroutine might get and of course you can crash/kill the whole program before the goroutine is finished but again: It is not helpful to think about this as a failure to start a goroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any possible way for this to fail, and if it is possible, it would result in a panic (and therefor application crash). I have never seen it happen, and I'm aware of examples of applications running *millions* of goroutines. The only limiting factor is available memory to allocate the goroutine stack.

`go foo()` is not like `pthread_create`. Goroutines are lightweight green threads handled by the Go runtime, and scheduled to run on OS threads. Starting a goroutine does not start a new OS thread.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian for the info. Is there any documentation to that effect? I find it tough to get to a standard documentation for GoLang.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for exactly for "standard documentation", the language spec and documentation for all stdlib packages is available on golang.org. A simple web search for "goroutines" turns up a ton of information.

Comment: Thanks, I could get the spec but it does not mention failure modes as it is equivalent to a function call I suppose. There is a lot of information but no mention of any failure, so I will assume that there is no failure.

Comment: Correct. There is no failure mode for starting a goroutine.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is not in starting a goroutine (which cannot "fail" per se) or that like but in the use of `sync.WaitGroup`. Your code has two **major** **bugs**:

1. You must do `wg.Add(1)` *before* launching the goroutine as otherwise the `Done()` could be executed before the `Add(1)`.
2. You *must* *not* copy a sync.WaitGroup. Your code makes a copy while calling myThread().

Both issues are explained in the official documentation to sync.WaitGroup and the given example in https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup